# Repeating perl script every 5 days, not nth day of month

Tags: linux, cron

I currently have one perl script that is used to make a memory intense call to another protocol. This takes approximately 20-25GB ram to complete. And, it takes anywhere from 8 to 15 minutes. Upon completion, I export that data to another perl script that processes it and submit to a discord bot for me.

The problem I'm having;

I need to run this code every 5 days. Not every 5th day of the week or months
but every 5 days. The protocol has new information available every 5 days, exactly.

If I use perl1 to call perl2 and have perl2 sleep for 431000 seconds (subtracting some time for the time it takes to even get perl2 involved) and then call perl1 again, is that a bad plan?

I started thinking I might have a lot of perl processes opening as p1 calls p2 and p2 a calls p1 again. I'm not even sure if I can sleep for ~ 5 days or the process will end itself. I know there is a better way to do this.

Investigating cron, nothing I could come up with or find really matches the scenario.

Let's say the time is October 20th at 4:44pm. The next data becomes available at October 25th at 4:44pm, then 30th, then November 4th and so on.

The time does not change. It is always at 4:44pm. I don't know the safest/most efficient way to achieve this. I'm already taxing my 16gb ram system with an 8gb swap to read the protocol data as-is, I don't want endless processes running holding up additional resources.

Server is on Ubuntu

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` isn't quite that flexible with this sort of thing and sleeping for five days at a time is not going to be entirely reliable in a couple of ways.

One solution would be to bake the "every five days" logic into a wrapper script and set it up in `cron` to run every single day.  So something like this is one approach:

```
unix_day=$(($(date +%s) / (60*60*24)))
modulus=$((unix_day % 5))
[ "${modulus}" -eq 0 ] && perl yourScript.pl
```

This is deterministic, it will run every 5 days based on number of days since epoch.

If you have a specific day you want to base the 5 days on, then this should do that.  In this example, the magic start date is the 13th October 2022 (yesterday) - you should set this as appropriate to your use case

```
my_epoch=$(($(date -d"2022-10-13 04:44" +%s) / (60*60*24)))
unix_day=$(($(date -d 04:44 +%s) / (60*60*24)))
modulus=$(((unix_day - my_epoch) % 5))
[ "${modulus}" -eq 0 ] && perl yourScript.pl
```

Comment: Indeed I may end up doing an epoch time and counting against that. I was hoping to avoid that but it probably would be the better way to handle it. The previous script maintainer just put it into cron to run every hour at 44mins and used some filtering to only pass along to perl 2 if time since lastEpoch start had passed. I definitely don't want to do that because of the taxing nature, every hour is way overkill. Thanks for the suggestion. It seems I may end up needing to go with an epoch count after all

Comment: I forgot to say thanks for your time. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `at`:

```
at -f script 16:44 + 5 days
```

will run the commands listed in `script` at 4:44pm five days from now.

You can use this to schedule a job every five days by having the job re-schedule itself. This should be the first thing it does, so that it will run again five days later regardless of what happens in the job.

`script` must contain shell commands, so it should contain the invocation of your Perl script; you can’t ask `at` to call your Perl script directly. The job will run as the user who called `at` in the first place, so you should run the first `at` (the manual invocation that kicks off the chain) as the appropriate user.

If you want to stop the chain by cancelling the next scheduled job, find its identifier with

```
atq
```

and delete it with `atrm`.